# ggplot2 no muestra nada o da error

Tags: r, ggplot2

estoy probando el paquete de R ggplot2.

He probado de distintas maneras y nunca consigo un resultado satisfactorio (mejor dicho, siempre fracaso). Estoy intentando hacer un grafico que me muestre el numero de consultas por año. Usando un `plot` por defecto de R funciona.

```
   output$grafico <- renderPlot({
        conn <- odbcConnect("ORAC11.ORACLE11G", uid="l21", pwd="l21", rows_at_time = 500, believeNRows=FALSE)
        a <- as.character(input$dateRange[1])
        b <- as.character(input$dateRange[2])


        consultaAgrupada <- sqlExecute(conn,
                                       query="select count(COCODIGO) NUMCOD, extract(year from COFECHA) ANIO from L2113T00 where extract(year from COFECHA) > extract(year from TO_DATE( ? ,'yyyy-mm-dd')) and extract(year from COFECHA) < extract(year from TO_DATE( ? ,'yyyy-mm-dd')) group by extract(year from COFECHA) ",
                                       data=data.frame(a,b),
                                       fetch = TRUE
        )

        close(conn)
        plot(consultaAgrupada$ANIO, consultaAgrupada$NUMCOD,     main="Numero de consultas por año"  ,  xlab="FECHA (AÑO)",     ylab="Nº CONSULTAS",col = c("blue","red","darkgreen"))    
    })
```

Hasta ahi todo bien, me muestra un grafico con puntos de las consultas por año, pero cuando pruebo con los graficos de ggplot2, o no se visualiza nada o me da un error

Por ejemplo, el codigo que tengo que no me visualiza nada es el siguiente( omito la parte en la que ejecuto la consulta ya que es lo mismo que en el primer ejemplo):

```
p <- ggplot(consultaAgrupada,aes(consultaAgrupada$ANIO,consultaAgrupada$NUMCOD))
print(p)
```

Esto me carga un grafico pero no me muestra datos
[image: Grafico sin datos]

La otra manera que he probado ha sido introducirle un `geomBar()`

```
p <- ggplot(consultaAgrupada,aes(consultaAgrupada$ANIO,consultaAgrupada$NUMCOD)+geomBar())
print(p)
```

Pero esto me da el error

> Error: non-numeric argument to binary operator

No he conseguido entender muy bien como crear los graficos en ggplot2 (como se puede ver ) asi que si alguien que me ilumina con su infinita sabiduria le estare eternamente agradecido :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primeor: en ggplot, los *aesthetics* son básicamente los nombres de las variables, o en su defecto, alguna transformación de las mismas.

```
ggplot(consultaAgrupada, aes(ANIO, NUMCOD))
```

Por otra parte, no existe la función `geomBar`, sino `geom_bar`, y está solamente necesita la variable `x` puesto que ella misma realiza el conteo. Por lo que en tu caso, asumiendo que tienes el valor y el conteo, necesitas de `geom_col`:

```
df <- data.frame(
  x = c(1, 2),    
  y = c(3, 5)
)

ggplot(df) + 
  geom_col(aes(x, y))
```

[image: geom_col]

```
df2 <- data.frame(
  x = c(rep(1, 3), rep(2, 5))
) 

ggplot(df2) + 
  geom_bar(aes(x))
```

[image: geom_bar]

Por último, a seguir leyendo sobre ggplot, no es fácil al comienzo, pero luego de aprender equivocándose es todo fácil!

Comment: Muchas gracias, funciona y me has aclarado un par de dudas, la verdad que esto de ggplot se me esta haciendo bastante cuesta arriba, si sabes de algun tutorial o similar me lo podrias enviar.

Comment: @AndoniAlda Ánimo, a mi también me costó mucho aprender lo básico, pero luego de un tiempo viene todo el beneficio de poder sacarle todo el poder que este paquete ofrece. Hay mucho material en la web, busca el que más te acomode :B.